# Install a windows service that points to a dynamic service location

Tags: c#, windows-services

Title is not great but I don't know how else to summarise what I want to do..

I have a windows .net service in C# that builds from TFS in a specific location as such

```
c:\TFS\App1\1.0.0.0\App.exe
c:\TFS\App1\1.0.0.1\App.exe
c:\TFS\App1\1.0.0.2\App.exe
```

I have another folder

```
c:\TFS\App1\Current
```

where I copy the latest version every time I build the service.
The installation path of the service on the windows machine is from the current folder, so I don't need do install/uninstall the service.

So the process of upgrading the service is currently the following:

```
1. Build
2. Stop Service
3. Copy from x.x.x.x folder to Current
4. Start Service
```

Is there a way to make some kind of a shortcut so that instead of copying the files every time I deploy something new, I just make a config change to point to the new location?

What I was thinking was maybe create a service that calls another service, but I don't know if this is possible.

e.g.
Install a service called "App1" that's running from "C:\TFS\ServiceStarter\Start.exe App1". 
The Start.exe.config file will contain the location of the service i want to run .

Whenever I do a new build, I go to the start.exe.config and change the path accordingly. Stop-Start the service and the new version is running.

The new way of upgrading would be:

```
1. Build
2. Change config file to point to X.X.X.X location
3. Restart service
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Couldn't you just write pre / post build events? that use the SC (service control) command and copy?

Comment: That would just automate the deployment. I need the deployment to still be manual so I will be in control like in a blue/green environment and just flip a switch in a config to point to the service version I want.

Comment: Is release and debug build not good enough?

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite what you are asking for, but it automates things a lot. You could use a simple bat file:

**Batch file commands:**

```
@REM If the batch file is going to run as as administrator, the starting path will be the system32 folder. With this we ensure that the starting path is the folder containing the batch file.
@cd /d "%~dp0"

@REM stop and delete the previous service using the service name
sc stop MyServiceName
sc delete MyServiceName

@REM ask for the version of the service
set /p version="Enter version: "

@REM create the path to executable
SET relativePath=%CD%
SET executablePath=%relativePath%\%version%\App.exe

@REM istall the service
sc create MyServiceName binPath= "%executablePath%" DisplayName= "MyServiceName"

@REM start the service
sc start MyServiceName

pause
```

**Batch file execution**

### [image]

---

So, you will need to:

1. Create the batch file.
2. Add the batch file to folder 'App1'
3. Run it as administrator
4. To target the correct version, just enter it in the command line

Now you should be able to switch to any version, just by executing the batch file.